# How can I create a custom control which evaluates to a list of values or replacements?

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, gui-construction

I have a set of variables which are used in various places in my calculations (solving a system, initial conditions, etc.). In order to make this easier to deal with, I want to make a control-like thing which makes them easier to manipulate, rather than just using long lists of unlabeled values such as

```
calculateValues[{0, 0, π, 0.5, 3}]
```

So far I have something like this:

[image]

This clearly doesn't work, and I expect in order to get it working properly I'll need to use `Interpretation` or more `Dynamic` incantations, but I can't figure out exactly what needs to happen. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
myControl[varNames_List, start_: 0] := 
 myControl[varNames, ConstantArray[start, Length@varNames]]

myControl[varNames_List, start_List] := 
 Interpretation[{vars = start}, 
  Panel[Grid[{varNames, 
     Array[InputField[Dynamic@vars[[#]], 
        FieldSize -> {{0, Infinity}, 1}] &, Length@vars]}]], vars]
```

Now you can run that function to create a control `myControl["a"~CharacterRange~"g"]`.
Each instance will have its own values and they all evaluate to their values when supplied as input

Comment: This works great, thanks! But what is the purpose of the `DynamicSetting` and `Evaluate`? It seems that if I remove them, it works just the same way. Also, I would expect to need `Dynamic[vars]` instead of `vars` at the end...

Comment: @jtbandes, without the `DynamicSetting` it shouldn't work as I thought you wanted. Try running `myControl["a"~CharacterRange~"g"]` and then adding `+3` to the output in the output cell with and without the `DynamicSetting`

Comment: The `Evaluate` is probably useless, but since `Interpretation` has attribute `HoldAll` and I don't know why it's not simply `HoldRest`, I wanted to make sure it evaluated the first argument. However, it seems to evaluate it anyway

Comment: The second argument of `Interpretation` needs to be what you want the kernel to receive when you use that control as input. You want the values of `vars`, and not a visual GUI that shows the dynamically updated value of `vars`. Always remember that `Dynamic` is only for SHOWING updated output (or in a control such as `Slider[Dynamic@..]` "as a notation" for input in controls).

Comment: To the kernel, `Dynamic[vars]` will always stay as `Dynamic[vars]` no matter if `vars` has a value. It's the front end who decides to show you a `Dynamic[vars]` as the dynamically updated value of `vars`, just like `Graphics[Disk[]]` will be shown as a black disk

Comment: @jtbandes, I just passed through the docs of `Interpretation` and saw that it can take an extra argument, specifying the local variables, and using it expands to the same code that I had used before: DynamicSetting@DynamicModule[..., but is way neater. Edited

Answer (score 2):

You could use [interpretation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html).

Here's the idea.

```
SetAttributes[makeDynamicPanel, HoldFirst]
makeDynamicPanel[x_, defaultValue_] :=
 Module[{y},
    y = 
       Interpretation[
          Panel@InputField[Dynamic[x]]
          ,
          x
       ];
    x = defaultValue;
    y
 ]
```

Then you do for example

```
makeDynamicPanel[z, {0, 0, π, 0.5, 3}]
```

and you get a panel that allows to edit the value of z and can be used as argument to your function, you can even do for example panel + 2 and get a valid value, it's quite practical.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using another list (`vals`) to store values for the variables `vars`. To set up a list of controllers (`InputField`s here) programmatically, some clever construct is required. Here I used an explicit `Function` call to save the changed value of the $i^{th}$ element of vals inside the `Dynamic` (as the `#` stands for the index of the list element, not the actual controller value, which is denoted as `$x`), but this can also be achieved using `With`.

```
calculateValues[v_List] := Plus @@ (v^Range@Length@v);

vars = {a, b, c, d, e};
vals = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Panel[
 Grid[{
   Text /@ vars,
   InputField[Dynamic[vals[[#]], Function[{$x}, vals[[#]] = $x]], 
      FieldSize -> {{0, Infinity}, 1}] & /@ Range@Length@vals
   }]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Dynamic@vals
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

```
calculateValues@vars
```

> ```
> a + b^2 + c^3 + d^4 + e^5
> ```

```
Dynamic[calculateValues@vars /. Thread[vars -> vals]]
```

> ```
> 3413
> ```