# How can I create some shorthand notation for a custom control?

Tags: front-end, functions, formatting

Per [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15089/how-can-i-create-a-custom-control-which-evaluates-to-a-list-of-values-or-replace), I have created a custom graphical control object which evaluates to a list of values. I would like to be able to create such an object quickly, rather than typing some command, pressing shift+enter, then copying the resulting object into wherever I want to use it. For example, something like typing `\[Theta]` which turns into `θ`... is it possible to create such a custom shorthand notation? (Even better, is it possible that when I start to type in a function which takes such a list as arguments, it pops up this control object for me to type the values in?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to [this control](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15099/109). You can

- Evaluate in a separate cell each time and copy paste (you don't like this)
- Write the command and evaluate in place
- Copy the control once and paste it several times: remember the variables were localized so each will have its own copy and they won't interfere
- Create a palette

  ```
  CreatePalette@PasteButton["Paste control", myControl["a"~CharacterRange~"g"]];
  ```
- Create a toolbar

  ```
  AppendTo[CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], DockedCells], 
   Cell@BoxData@
     ToBoxes@PasteButton["Paste control", 
       myControl["a"~CharacterRange~"g"]]]
  ```
- Create an input alias, or an input auto replacement. Example of input alias (the other one is the same)

  ```
  AppendTo[CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], InputAliases], 
   "control" -> ToBoxes@myControl["a"~CharacterRange~"g"]]
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to find `InputAutoReplacements` which was what I wanted. Do you have any idea why it selects a random field/object in the box instead of highlighting the first text field when the replacement happens?

Comment: @jtbandes not off the top of my head. Generally `\[SelectionPlaceholder]`s are used to represent where the selection will go so you could try initializing the control with that character