# Add ribbon of most used commands-How it could be implemented?

Tags: front-end, customization

A few days ago I saw a video, I can't remember where and what was special about it was that under the commands in the main panel there was a row with the most used commands.
How can you implement this for particular purposes in such a way that when you start mathematics it always appears.

[image]

Comment: See if you can look up “DockedCells”. (I’m away from Mma at present.)

Comment: How about this: [DevTools`NotebookActions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212851/5478)?

Comment: [more examples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15116/5478)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beside Mathematica built-in `Palettes` which are basically floating window, you can access with `Palettes` option in Menu Bar, there are also some built-in toolbar in `Window > Toolbar` which will be shown below menu bar just like the picture you mentioned.

If you want to create your own floating Palette, follow this [Tutorial on Wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CreatingPalettes.html).
If you want to create toolbar, see this [Tutorial on Wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToToolbars.html).

Comment: I am looking at your indications, what is not clear to me is how to install the palette so that it appears whenever I start mathematica, could you give a simple example, it is all in English, there are some things that I do not understand well

Comment: @rpujadas if you quit mma with the palette open then it will be open next time you launch mma.